# can anyone help me explain mongo insert process when duplicate key error happened?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, error-handling

When I try to use db.collection.insert(document), the inserted document is an array, when one element of the array occurred duplication error, can all the other elements in this array be successfully inserted into the collection?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the ordered parameter as false, the insert statement will insert all documents except the duplicate documents.

For example :

```
db.products.insertMany( [
      { _id: 10, item: "large box", qty: 20 },
      { _id: 11, item: "small box", qty: 55 },
      { _id: 11, item: "medium box", qty: 30 },
      { _id: 12, item: "envelope", qty: 100},
      { _id: 13, item: "stamps", qty: 125 },
      { _id: 13, item: "tape", qty: 20},
      { _id: 14, item: "bubble wrap", qty: 30}
   ], { ordered: false } );
```

In the above insert statement, all document will be inserted except the duplicate it 11 and 13.